# FUNcube Dongle antenna specs

Tags: antenna, software-defined-radio, satellites

What are the specs of the [FUNcube Dongle antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2211/idea-for-better-reception-in-crowded-city)? I mean, how to fully describe only the antenna?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you provide your own antenna for the FUNcube (but this isn't explicitly stated anywhere I can find on their web site).  If you want to know the specs for the specific antenna the person in the post you link to used, you should probably ask him directly.